# Why isnt my Web API reacting to my requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently trying to post to my Web API which has a controller like this.

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
    {


        [HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        public IHttpActionResult PostNewUser(UserModel data)
        {

            if (data.Username == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

From a C# console application using the `HttpClient`
doing this.

```
var User = new UserModel
            {
                Username = "admin",
                Password = "password",
                HWID_Hash = "password"
            };

            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(User);

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var stringContent = new StringContent(output);

            var response = await client.PostAsync($"http://localhost:51838/api/product/PostNewUser", stringContent);
            if (response.ReasonPhrase.ToLower() == "not found")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User doesn't exist.");
            }

            if (response.ReasonPhrase.ToLower() == "ok")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome.");
            }
```

But when I put a breakpoint in the Web API it doesnt even react to the request that I am sending from the console application.

Why is that?

Comment: Add `[FromBody]` attribute before action method parameter like this: `public IHttpActionResult PostNewUser([FromBody] UserModel data)`. Also, you dont need `AcceptVerbs("POST")` attribute.

Comment: Still doesnt react.

Comment: client.PostASync returns `StatusCode = UnsupportedMediaType`

Comment: Try initializing `var stringContent = new StringContent(output, Encoding.UTF8, "applicaiton/json");`

Comment: That did the trick

Comment: Great! I have posted the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `[FromBody]` attribute before action method parameter like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostNewUser([FromBody] UserModel data)
```

Also, specify the content type for the json string content like this:

```
stringContent = new StringContent(output, Encoding.UTF8, "applicaiton/json")
```